# "npm run build" is failing, it seems npm isn't recognizing ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm building a web app with Vue.js and Flask. On my laptop I am able to run `npm run build` to compile the Vue app and deposit the various created static files in the appropriate folders in my Flask app, and the app runs.

When I try to do this on a remote server (PythonAnywhere.com), I get an error when I run `npm run build`. It says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`, and it seems to be complaining about the use of a `=>` in the build.js file.

When I opened up the build.js file in PyCharm I actually saw the linter complaining about the same point in the code; when I updated PyCharm to use ES6, the linter stopped complaining.

Here are the versions of node and npm being used on the remote server:

- node v0.10.37
- npm  v3.10.6

How do I get this remote server to handle ES6 syntax when running `npm run build`?

Comment: Please include the versions of Node.js and npm on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update node on the remote server.